# Nodejs fs.copyfile not allowed for copy a file to the destination folder

Tags: node.js

I am trying to copy a file from one location to another so I'm using this:

```
fs.copyFile('C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\myfile.zip', c:\\myfiles
  console.log('file was copied successfully!');
});
```

I can see that the destination folder is readonly so that's why I'm getting this.

How can I change it's status on my windows pc.

I've tried this but nothing is happening and I still get the error:

```
fs.chmodSync('c:\\myfiles', 0o755);
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Windows, I guest `C:\` is your system disk (where you install the Windows).

If you want to write a file to `c:\myfiles` , it require you Administrator permission (you can try by way: copy and paste a file to the folder, by hand).

Solution:

- Option1: Change your folder, ex: D:\myfiles
- Option2: Use windows file manager, change your folder permission (everyone read/write)